# Tag wiki edit not shown in achievements list

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

After a tag wiki edit I made, it got approved, and I got two reputation points:

[image: Tag wiki edit reputation change]

While the achievements dropdown displays the reputation change correctly, the tag wiki edit is not listed there:

[image: Missing tag wiki edit reputation change]